# What is run() function doing in ProxyThread class if is not called anywhere?

Tags: java, multithreading, proxy

This is the class containing the `main()` method:

```
public class MultithreadedProxyServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        boolean listening = true;

        int port = 10000;   //default
        try {
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //ignore me
            System.out.println("gnore");
        }

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Started on: " + port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: " + args[0]);
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        while (listening) {
            new ProxyThread(serverSocket.accept()).start();
        }
        serverSocket.close();
    }
}
```

And this is the ProxyThread class:

```
public class ProxyThread extends Thread {


    private Socket socket = null;
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 32768;

    public ProxyThread(Socket socket) {
        super("ProxyThread");
        this.socket = socket; //initialzed my parent before you initalize me

    }

    public void run() {
        //get input from user
        //send request to server
        //get response from server
        //send response to user
        System.out.println("run");

        try {
            DataOutputStream out = 
                new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine, outputLine;
            int cnt = 0;
            String urlToCall = "";
            ///////////////////////////////////
            //begin get request from client
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                try {
                    StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(inputLine);
                    tok.nextToken();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("break");
                    break;
                }
                //parse the first line of the request to find the url
                if (cnt == 0) {
                    String[] tokens = inputLine.split(" ");
                    urlToCall = tokens[1];
                    //can redirect this to output log
                    System.out.println("Request for : " + urlToCall);
                }

                cnt++;
            }
            //end get request from client
            ///////////////////////////////////


            BufferedReader rd = null;
            try {
                //System.out.println("sending request
                //to real server for url: "
                //        + urlToCall);
                ///////////////////////////////////
                //begin send request to server, get response from server
                URL url = new URL(urlToCall);
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                //not doing HTTP posts
                conn.setDoOutput(false);
                //System.out.println("Type is: "
                //+ conn.getContentType());
                //System.out.println("content length: "
                //+ conn.getContentLength());
                //System.out.println("allowed user interaction: "
                //+ conn.getAllowUserInteraction());
                //System.out.println("content encoding: "
                //+ conn.getContentEncoding());
                //System.out.println("content type: "
                //+ conn.getContentType());

                // Get the response
                InputStream is = null;
                HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection)conn;
                if (conn.getContentLength() > 0) {
                    is = conn.getInputStream();
                    rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                }
                //end send request to server, get response from server
                ///////////////////////////////////

                ///////////////////////////////////
                //begin send response to client
                byte by[] = new byte[ BUFFER_SIZE ];
                int index = is.read( by, 0, BUFFER_SIZE );
                while ( index != -1 )
                {
                  out.write( by, 0, index );
                  index = is.read( by, 0, BUFFER_SIZE );
                }
                out.flush();

                //end send response to client
                ///////////////////////////////////
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //can redirect this to error log
                System.err.println("Encountered exception: " + e);
                //encountered error - just send nothing back, so
                //processing can continue
                out.writeBytes("");
            }

            //close out all resources
            if (rd != null) {
                rd.close();
            }
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
            if (socket != null) {
                socket.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have copy-pasted the above code from the internet, however I am having difficulties running it.

Comment: Could you tell us more about the difficulties you have encountered?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question from the post title, the `run()` method from ProxyThread class is called by JVM, after the thread has been started `new ProxyThread(serverSocket.accept()).start();` and it usually contains the actual work that a thread should performed (in this case, it handles whatever the server socket receives and it accepts a connection from a client).
The moment when JVM calls `run()` method cannot be controlled by the programmer, but is after the thread has been started.

run() method is never called explicitly by the programmer.